# how do you apply a function to create a column and insert value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df

Server        Model
Server1dc     xp2
server2dc     cc4
server4uat    dd4
```

I have this function to determine the number of slots given the model:

```
def total_slot(row):
   if "xp" in row["Model"]:
     return 5
   if "cc" in row["Model"]:
     return 10
   return 0
```

I need to apply this total_slot function to my data frame (df) and create a new column called total_slots:

```
df['total_slots']=df.apply(total_slot, axis=1)
```

It works but I get this working message:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe.

How else I could do this?

resulting df needs to look like this:

```
Server        Model total_slots
Server1dc     xp2    5
server2dc     cc4    10
server4uat    dd4    0
```

Comment: I imagine `total_slot` is slightly different since it is currently syntactically incorrect (missing `:`)

Comment: The problem is not your line of code. Your dataframe is already a copy before setting the column. Before your line, insert this line `print(df._is_copy)`. What is the output? (You should provide the code before `apply` to help us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this warning and correctly add the 'total_slots' column to your DataFrame, you can use the apply function with a [lambda function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-apply-with-lambda-examples/#:%7E:text=apply()%20can%20be%20used,arguments%20and%20execute%20an%20expression.) or a list comprehension. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Server': ['Server1dc', 'server2dc', 'server4uat'],
        'Model': ['xp2', 'cc4', 'dd4']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the total_slot function
def total_slot(row):
    if "xp" in row["Model"]:
        return 5
    if "cc" in row["Model"]:
        return 10
    return 0

# Apply the function using a lambda function
df['total_slots'] = df.apply(lambda row: total_slot(row), axis=1)

print(df)
```

or using list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Server': ['Server1dc', 'server2dc', 'server4uat'],
        'Model': ['xp2', 'cc4', 'dd4']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the total_slot function
def total_slot(model):
    if "xp" in model:
        return 5
    if "cc" in model:
        return 10
    return 0

# Use list comprehension to compute total_slots
df['total_slots'] = [total_slot(model) for model in df['Model']]

print(df)
```

You can check on my kaggle link [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebook77427a10dc)

Comment: @HeinzHiahaan, It works but trowing an warning messages, the same

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and give me `pip list`? I am using `pandas  2.0.3` on kaggle

Comment: I am using pandas version 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Python3.10, aside from the missing colons in the custom function:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
df = pd.DataFrame({"Model": {"1dc": "xp2", "2dc": "cc4", "4uat": "dd4"}})                                             
                                                                                                                      
def total_slot(row):                                                                                                  
   if "xp" in row["Model"]:                                                                                           
     return 5                                                                                                         
   if "cc" in row["Model"]:                                                                                           
     return 10                                                                                                        
   return 0                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
df['total_slots']=df.apply(total_slot, axis=1)                                                                        
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, the real problem occurs earlier in the code:

```
# Minimal Working Example
data = {'Server': ['Server1dc', 'server2dc', 'server4uat'],
        'Model': ['xp2', 'cc4', 'dd4']}
ds = pd.DataFrame(data)  # Note the name of the original dataframe "ds" and not "df"
```

Your code is good from a fresh dataframe:

```
df = ds.copy()  # create a copy or subset your dataframe properly

print('Is `df` a copy?', df._is_copy or 'No')
df['total_slots'] = df.apply(lambda row: total_slot(row), axis=1)  # No warning
print(df)

# Output
Is `df` a copy? No
       Server Model  total_slots
0   Server1dc   xp2            5
1   server2dc   cc4           10
2  server4uat   dd4            0
```

Now if I make a bad operation before:

```
df = ds[:]  # create a bad copy or subset your dataframe incorrectly

print('Is `df` a copy?', df._is_copy or 'No')
df['total_slots'] = df.apply(lambda row: total_slot(row), axis=1)  # SettingWithCopyWarning
print(df)

# Output
Is `df` a copy? <weakref at 0x7fc419cb3b80; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7fc4218b7b20>

SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

       Server Model  total_slots
0   Server1dc   xp2            5
1   server2dc   cc4           10
2  server4uat   dd4            0
```

As you can see the operation is still the same but now it raises a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. You have to look upstream in the code to know when you have done something wrong.

More information here:

- [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15239951)
- [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)
- [Evaluation order matters](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters)